# Null is given when trying to find data from pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-session

I have a Many To Many relationship between **User** & **Wallet** Models:

`Wallet.php`:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_wallet','wallet_id','user_id')->withPivot('balance');
    }
```

`User.php`:

```
public function wallets()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Wallet::class,'user_wallet','user_id','wallet_id')->withPivot('balance');
    }
```

And the pivot table `user_wallet` goes like this:

[image]

Then at the Controller, I need to access the `balance` field:

```
public function chargeWallet(Request $request, $wallet, $user)
{ 
            // $wallet is wallet_id (2) & $user is user_id (373)
            $bal = Wallet::with("users")
                ->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($user) {
                    $query->where('id',$user);
                })->where('id', $wallet)->first();
            dd($bal->balance);
}
```

But now I get `null` as the result of `dd($bal->balance)` !!

So what is wrong here? How can I properly get the `balance` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it is a Many to Many relationships, you have Users attached to many Wallets, and Wallets attach to many Users. For each relation between a single Wallet and a single User: you have a pivot value (`pivot` relation). From your query, you'll retrieve Wallet with Users, each user's having the `pivot` relation value attached. So to retrieve the pivot table data (for each relation) you have to use a loop (added a `with` callback to make sure that only Users with matching user_id are eager loaded with the Wallets):

```
$bal = Wallet::with(["users"=>function ($query) use ($user) {
                $query->where('user_id',$user);
            }])
            ->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($user) {
                $query->where('user_id',$user);
            })->find($wallet);
```

To avoid repeating same callback (`where user_id =`) you can assign it to variable:

```
$callback = function ($query) use ($user) {
     $query->where('user_id',$user);
};
```

then use it in your query:

```
 $bal = Wallet::with(['users' => $callback])
                ->whereHas('users', $callback)->find($wallet);
```

and then use a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($bal->users as $value){
   dd($value->pivot->balance);
}
```

or

if you only want to return the pivot value for the first User of the first Wallet of your query, then:

```
$user = $bal->users->first();
dd($user->pivot->balance);
```

Comment: Note that using a many to many between Users and Wallets means that "2 or more users can share the same wallet". And storing the (main) balance on the pivot table means you can do something like "2 or more users share the same wallet, but for those users the balance for this same wallet ID is different". In a more classic way, a User can have Many wallets, but a wallet can only be owned by 1 user, it would then require a belongsTo/hasMany relationship (Users hasMany Wallets, Wallets belongsTo User). And the balance would be stored on the wallet table.

Comment: @Mtxz thaks for adding more details